How to find node voltage in this relatively simple DC circuit with all passive elements?
Below is an image of a circuit from an exam I took where we were instructed to calculate the voltage at the node Vx. Specifically we were instructed to use the method of superposition to find the voltage. On the exam, I used that method and came up with -30 volts for the voltage there. Likewise I used other circuit analysis methods (namely, I transformed the 10 V source to an equivalent current source and reduced the circuit) and obtained the same voltage at that node. Please note for the problem that the current source on the right is a dependent current source.
I was marked incorrect. Could anyone please enlighten me as to what the actual voltage at this node is? You are welcome to use any method you please (even computer software, which I'm not able to use) to obtain the voltage, we were just specifically instructed to use superposition.



Have you used a simulator to check your answer and your calculation process? You could even verify each step of the superposition, by applying one source at a time.

I'd love to do that, unfortunately I'm new to this whole thing and haven't used a simulator and one's that i've googled are too technical for my level (i'm currently an early undergraduate student). could you suggest a user-friendly (preferably browser version?) of a simulator?

@AdamCain One that's commonly suggested here is Paul Falstad's simulator - it has its limitations compared to more powerful simulators like SPICE suites or Cadence ADE, but for a circuit like this it should be quite capable, and have much better ease-of-use.

Falstad will happily calculate a solution even under impossible boundary conditions and not complain that the solution doesn't converge, so you better verify the result you get by hand afterwards :)

Your answer in part A (-27.69) seems correct.  Your answer in part B (-2.31) is incorrect.  Try using superposition again, opening the 3 A current source and maybe use the Thevenin equivalent of the 10 V source and 2 resistors to simplify the problem.

@John, I redid it the way you suggested and arrive at Thevenin equivalent voltage of 30/23 Volts and a Thevenin resistance of of 240/46 Ohms. Unsure of how to use that information to obtain Vx now. could you perhaps clarify where to go from there?

The answer given is correct.  $V_1 = 3A * 40\Omega||6\Omega||(-\frac{1}{0.3})\Omega = 3A* 40\Omega||-7.5\Omega = 3* -\frac{120}{13}\Omega = -\frac{360}{13} \approx -27.69V$
$V_2 = 10V * \frac{6\Omega||(-\frac{1}{0.3})\Omega}{40\Omega + 6\Omega||(-\frac{1}{0.3})\Omega} = 10V * \frac{-7.5\Omega}{40\Omega + (-7.5)\Omega} = 10V * \frac{-7.5 \Omega}{32.5\Omega} \approx -2.307V$

@G36, that's what i thought... can't for the life of me figure out why i was i penalized

I do not know because you haven't shown us your solution.

@AdamCain Perhaps your solution is correct, and I made an error in my quick literally back of the actual envelope calculation.  I'll recheck.

@AdamCain Indeed, I did confirm that you and G36 are correct, sorry for the confusion!

thank you John D!
@G36, i did not show my work, no, but the above answers filled in are my answers (not the instructors') and they match what you came up with.
I produced each V_x contribution by eliminating independent voltage sources one at a time, performing node analysis on each, and summing the contributions at the end. Later on when i can access my tablet, perhaps i can upload a picture of my work. but all the same, we obtain the same answer.

Adam, I converted the 10 V source and the 40 Ohm resistor to its Norton. That gives a net 3.25 A source into Vx with a 40 Ohm resistor in parallel with the 6 Ohm resistor. So the equation to solve for Vx is: (3.0 A + 0.25 A + 0.3*Vx)*(40 Ohm || 6 Ohm) = Vx. One equation, one unknown, that does yield Vx = -30 V.

Since I'm new to StackExchange, i'm not sure how to comment with a picture of my work, but here's a link to two screenshots of the work i submitted for the exam. I realize my approach could be tidier (both in method, and literally i could write tidier), but every step I took looks consistent to me.
Part 1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CldaVDE7kv5DEIUSzzOnaz-HAdRaNNJv/view
Part 2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KzA2P1mO8ykPVWaZl_4mMu0v0ZF6qlRx/view
@periblepsis thank you btw for putting the effort in! confirms my suspicion there's a grading mistake

@AdamCain I don't see a problem with either page you showed. The approach was fine. The results fine. The final answer correct. I already wrote out the final equation to solve. But here are your two: V1: solve(Eq((3+3/10*V1)*(40 || 6), V1), V1) gives -360/13 and V2: solve(Eq(V2/40+V2/6, 10/40+3/10*V2), V2) gives -30/13. Adding those two provides the final answer. Good job. Keep it up. And find a different teacher/school? (+1 to the question.)

This is not a proper answer, but shows the steps using a simulator.
Using the lazy method of using LTspice (a free SPICE simulator), the simulator answers agree with yours using the steps for superposition. I would encourage you to learn some sort of SPICE simulator as this is a good skill to have.
I'm guessing you didn't use superposition properly or your solution was hard to interpret, thus the markdown. The classes I took in he dark ages, the final numeric answer holds very little weight, the solution process holds lots of weight.
Show us the steps you took using superposition in your post.


i will certainly make it a point to learn these softwares in the near future. Thanks for the solution and advice!

The network in its simplicity is suitable for the application of Millman's theorem:

